# Update records in ms access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

My current table looks as follows;

[image: Before Update].

I would want to be able to update this table so that it looks like this table;

[image: After Update].

My Goal is to update the 0 values of the PL YTD records with incremented values from PLMonthly records as shown in the 2nd screenshot.
Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Have you tried it yet? There shouldn't be anything hard about it is just going to be long since you will be adding columns together in your SQL. Is this table only two rows or is there a Year column too?

Comment: No, this is just a mock up of what I expect to get ... not really sure on how to go about in in Access sql ... any ideas?

Comment: So that table only stores one year of data? if not then you'll need to add the appropriate grouping to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a lot of repetition...

```
SELECT "PLYTD" AS Name, 
    [PL].JanActual AS JanActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual] AS FebActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual] AS MarActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual] AS AprActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual] AS MayActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual]+[PL].[JunActual] AS JunActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual]+[PL].[JunActual]+[PL].[JulActual] AS JulActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual]+[PL].[JunActual]+[PL].[JulActual]+[PL].[AugActual] AS AugActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual]+[PL].[JunActual]+[PL].[JulActual]+[PL].[AugActual]+[PL].[SepActual] AS SepActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual]+[PL].[JunActual]+[PL].[JulActual]+[PL].[AugActual]+[PL].[SepActual]+[PL].[OctActual] AS OctActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual]+[PL].[JunActual]+[PL].[JulActual]+[PL].[AugActual]+[PL].[SepActual]+[PL].[OctActual]+[PL].[NovActual] AS NovActual, 
    [PL].[JanActual]+[PL].[FebActual]+[PL].[MarActual]+[PL].[AprActual]+[PL].[MayActual]+[PL].[JunActual]+[PL].[JulActual]+[PL].[AugActual]+[PL].[SepActual]+[PL].[OctActual]+[PL].[NovActual]+[PL].[DecActual] AS DecActual
FROM PL
WHERE (((PL.Name)="PLMonthly"));
```

Once you have that an update or append query, depending on if the **PLYTD** row already exists or not, and you are good to go. You can either nest it in the FROM or just build a query out of it and reference it like I did below...

```
UPDATE PL INNER JOIN plytd_query AS ytd ON PL.Name = ytd.Name SET 
    PL.JanActual = [ytd].[JanActual], 
    PL.FebActual = [ytd].[FebActual], 
    PL.MarActual = [ytd].[MarActual], 
    PL.AprActual = [ytd].[AprActual], 
    PL.MayActual = [ytd].[MayActual], 
    PL.JunActual = [ytd].[JunActual], 
    PL.JulActual = [ytd].[JulActual], 
    PL.AugActual = [ytd].[AugActual], 
    PL.SepActual = [ytd].[SepActual], 
    PL.OctActual = [ytd].[OctActual], 
    PL.NovActual = [ytd].[NovActual], 
    PL.DecActual = [ytd].[DecActual]
```

That makes some assumptions but it should get you started in the right direction anyway.

Comment: Thanks Omnikrys ... does look like a good place to start, despite all the repetition, I'll run with this for now and see how it goes